# BTRFS: error (device dm-0) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2150: errno=-5 10 failure

Tags: fedora, mount, btrfs, automounting, systemd-mount

I have run this error while trying to boot my fedora linux 36 from my external SSD. I did boot it at home yesterday quite well, shut it down this morning. When I got to work today and tried booting it I got this error: `BTRFS: error (device dm-0) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2150: errno=-5 10 failure`

I cannot boot into my fedora.
I cannot access tty
I cannot boot into troubleshooting mode.

I have tried booting kernel 35 which is also installed but I still have the same error.

What should I do?

Comment: Wow, I'm back with the same problem after 6 months. Last time I had to reinstall fedora after several `chroot` failure attempts. Anyone have a solution for this.